i18next/locize - How do i know the user's language in my backend
I am considering integration i18next with Locize in my stack (react webapp, react native app, nest-js backend) , but i am lost on some things. So i get the concept of initializing i18next clientside with a certain language, which is retrieved either by some language detection or just a simple "select your language" toggle. Then connects to Locize backend and it serves the correct language to the frontend.
We are using an SDUI approach for the app, which means that somewhere in the backend a piece of code will do something like i18next.t('my.key') and put the result into a JSON and serve it to the app. My first question is then, how does the backend instance know which language to serve? The backend knows the user's preferred language because it is kept on the res object, but how does the i18next instance know? Does it magically take this language from the initial http request, assuming that there is a language header in there somewhere, it binds the language to the user's session and from that point on, it automagically presents the user with the right language? I was expecting the i18next.t() method to take in a language param, but it doesn't seem to do that.
The second question is, how does it know the user's language if an action is not actually triggered by the user itself. Let's say there is a cronjob that needs to do something that involves a translated string. Let's say it's a message that goes to a bunch of users with different languages. How does it know what language to pick?
Is there a piece of documentation i am missing? There is this article that mentions what it looks like, but it doesn't really tell me that much.
Went through the documentation of both locize and i18next, and before i start implementing or building a proof of concept, i want to know if there are things that i have missed
